# Why doesn't refresh the page using Ajax ? What is technique behind use for it

Tags: ajax

I want know what is reason behind use technique why not refresh the page using ajax and why refresh the page submitting form using HTTP

Comment: Please, could you share the code you are using and give more details?

Comment: Thanks for response,
I have just asked the question why is not refresh the page using ajax and why refresh the page without ajax . what are technology used behind it  

Thanks Best Regards